# How to update variables on view change

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Hello I'm having problems updating a variable once it has been set and the value changes on the view. When I search for a video and click on it, it starts playing, but when I search for another video and click play nothing happens. I'm require to refresh the browser in order to search for another video.

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css">
    <script src="js/lib/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>



<!-- The Templates -->

<!--start home -->


<div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="b">



    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>welcome</h1>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slidedown" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>



   <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content">

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content"  >
    <h2>Browse Channels</h2>
    <form class="ui-filterable" >
      <input id="myFilter" data-type="search">
    </form>
    <ul id = "users" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:200px;" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" >

    </ul>
</div>
   </div>



<div style="text-align:center"> 
<br>
  <video controls  id="video1" width=420>


  </video>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
} 

</script> 


 <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>


  </div> 


</div>






<!--end home -->



    <!-- The Scripts -->

<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>


<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



</body>

</html>
```

This is my main.js

```
(function() {
/* model */
var m3u8model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            channel: "",
            url: ""
        }
    }

    });
/* Collection */

var m3u8collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: m3u8model, /* binding the model to the collection */
    url: "m3u8.json", /* path to Json File */
    parse: function(response){
    return response.channels;
    }

    });

var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#users",

    collection: new m3u8collection(), /* bind Collection into the view*/

/* Benging fetching collection uppon the view initiation */

    initialize: function(){


    var self = this;
   this.collection.fetch({ /*underscore fetch method, to fetch the json objects from the collection*/

      success: function() { /* if fetch success continue */
        self.render();
      }
    });        
    },


  /* Events */

    events:{
        "click": "onClick"

    },

    onClick: function(e) {
        var link = ($(e.target).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();

        this.$el.append(myVideo.play());
         e.preventDefault();

        var vid = new VideoView({pos: link, el: "#video1"});
        vid.render();
    },


/* End of Events */





   /* End View initiation, and fetch pass the values to the render method. */


     render: function() {
    var scope = this;
    this.collection.forEach(function(model) {
      scope.output(model);
    });
    return this;
  },

  output: function(model) {
    var row = document.createElement("li");
    row.innerHTML = 
        " <a href="+ model.get("url")+">"+ model.get("channel")+"</a>";    
    this.el.appendChild(row);

  }
});


var VideoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (attrs) {


    this.options = attrs;
},



    render: function(){

            var row = document.createElement("li");
    row.innerHTML = 
        this.$el.append(" <source src="+this.options.pos+">"+"type="+"application/x-mpegURL autoplay");    
    this.el.appendChild(row);


       return this;


      /*
             this.$el.append("<source src="+this.options.pos+ "type="+'application/x-mpegURL');

      this.$el.append("hello"+this.options.pos); */
       return this;

    }

    });


var app = new UsersView();



})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some confusing things going on in your code. I don't understand why you are appending `li` elements to your `video#video1` element. It seems to me that what you want to do is to update the `src` attribute of `video#video1` when a link in your `ul#users` list. I would get rid of `VideoView` which is doing nobody any good and update the `onClick` method in the `UsersView` to the following:

```
onClick: function(e) {
    var src = $(e.target).attr('href');

    myVideo.setAttribute('src', src);
    myVideo.play();
    e.preventDefault();
},
```